# regex to match only quotes that aren't in links

Tags: javascript, regex

can you tell me how I can in javascript using regex to select quoted text, but not the one that is in the link

so I don't want to select these quotes `<a href="some link">some text</a>`
I want to select only normal quoted text

I used

```
result = content.replace(/"(.*?)"/g, "<i>$1</i>");
```

to replace all quoted text with italic, but it replaces also href quotes

Thanks :)

Comment: Consider providing a more comprehensible test case showing the expected behavior.

Comment: ok, so ClasG got it right. I have some content like: <p>This "quoted" <a href="not this">Nor "this"</a> but "this"</p>. I want to select only quotes outside of the "a" tag.

Comment: But what are the text nodes? Are they inside `p` tags?

Comment: They mostly are, but that's not obligatory. It can be also in some other tag, or out of the tag completely. I have no control over what content will authors provide. All I need is regex, like one I showed, that will beside selecting quoted text, exclude quotes that are inside of the "a" tag.

Comment: Please check this approach - http://jsfiddle.net/9c87ghdn/

Comment: Great :) It works. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I added an answer, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need an adhoc regex solution, you may match and capture tags, and only replace `"` symbols in other contexts. Defining a tag as `<`+non-`<`s up to the first `>`, we may use

```js
var s = '"replace this" but <div id="not-here"><a href="not this"></a> "and here"</div>';
var re = /(<[^<]*?>)|"(.*?)"/g;
var result = s.replace(re, function (m,g1,g2) {
  return g1? g1 : '<i>' + g2 + '</i>';
});
console.log(result);
```

The `(<[^<]*?>)|"(.*?)"` matches:

- `(<[^<]*?>)` - Group 1 (`g1` later in the callback) that captures `<`, 0+ symbols other than `<` as few as possible up to the first `>`
- `|` - or
- `"(.*?)"` - `"`, 0+ chars other than a newline as few as possible captured into Group 2 (`g2` later) and a `"`.

In the callback method, Group 1 is checked for a match, and if yes, we just put the tag back into the result, else, replace with the tags.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer would be to use:

```
/[^=]"(.*)"/
```

instead of

```
/"(.*?)"/
```

But that will also include quotes that have = sign before them.

Comment: This will select every quotes, with some character before them, except ones that have = sign before quotes. This won't work

Answer (score 0):

Why not only work on the actual text of the element... Like:

```js
var anchors = [],
    idx;

anchors = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("a"));
for(idx=0; idx<anchors.length; idx++) {
    anchors[idx].innerHTML = anchors[idx].innerHTML.replace(/"([^"]*)"/g, '<i>$1</i>');
}
```

```html
<a href="some link">some text that contains a "quoted" part.</a>
<br/>
<a href="another link">more "text" that contains a "quoted" part.</a>
```

Here we get all anchor elements as an array and replace the `innerHTML` text with a *italicized* version of itself.

Comment: but I don't want to select ones that are in the link. I want to select only quoted text outside of the link

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. You mean the text completely outside the `<a>` tags? Like `<p>This "quoted" <a href="not this">Nor "this"</a> but "this"</p>`?

Answer (score 0):

This pattern could be what you're looking for: `<.+>.*(\".+\").*</.+>`

Used in JavaScript, the following matches "text":

`new RegExp('<.+>.*(\".+\").*</.+>', 'g').exec('<a href="some link">some "text"</a>')[1]`